# CakePHP: Filters and foreign keys! Not working

Tags: cakephp, filter, foreign-key-relationship

What I am trying to understand here is, what does this error mean and what am I doing wrong? I must be screwing up with the naming convention.

My models are product and category. Category has the hasMany and products has the belongsTo.

http://webdesign4.georgianc.on.ca/~100141468/comp2084/todo/products/add

http://webdesign4.georgianc.on.ca/~100141468/comp2084/todo/products/filter/9

name y

pass y

**ProductsController**

```
function filter($category_id) {
            $this->set('Product',$this->Product->findAllByCategoryId($category_id));
        }
```

**add**

```
$this->loadModel('Category');
$this->set('Categorys',$this->Category->find('list',array('order'=> array('Category.name'))));
```

**filter.ctp**

```
<? foreach($Product as $row): ?>
     <tr><td>
<?=$row['Product']['id']?>
</td><td>
<?=$row['Product']['name']?>
</td><td>
<?=$row['Product']['price']?>
</td><td>
<?=$row['Category']['name']?>
</td><td>
<a href="edit/<?=$row['Product']['id']?>">Edit</a>
    </td></tr>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

**add.ctp**

```
<?php
        echo $this ->Form->input('name');
        echo $this ->Form->input('description');
        echo $this ->Form->input('price');
        echo $this ->Form->input('file', array('type' => 'file'));
        echo $this ->Form->input('Category_id');
        echo $this ->Form->end('submit',true); 
        ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Start by doing a `debug($Product);` Do you see a `Category` key? If not, either set recursive higher or even better use `Containable`.

For your add, change the view var name to `categories` and change the form input field to `category_id` (That is if you've followed convention in your database and that's just a typo)

If category is related to products, there's no need for `loadModel`.

Simply do `$this->Product->Category->find...`

Comment: Eh, would it be safe to say that it is not connected correctly because the filters are not working?

Answer (score 1):

this is very simple..you are not grasping the cake fundamentals. I would suggest reading through the book and the tutorial again, focusing on the naming conventions and associations.

You need these associations in place:

```
//product.php
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Category' => array(
        'className' => 'Category',
        'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ));


// category.php
var $hasMany = array(
    'Product' => array(
        'className' => 'Product',
        'foreignKey' => 'category_id'
    )
);



// products_controller.php
function filter($category_id) {
    $this->set('products', $this->Product->findAllByCategoryId($category_id));
}

function add() {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->Product->create();
        if ($this->Product->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Product has been saved', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Product could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
        }
    }
    $categories = $this->Product->Category->find('list');   
    $this->set(compact(array('categories')));
}

   // filter.ctp
   debug($products); // just to see what data has been returned

   // add.ctp
   echo $this->Form->create('Product');
   echo $this->Form->input('name');
   echo $this->Form->input('description');
   echo $this->Form->input('price');
   echo $this->Form->input('file', array('type' => 'file'));
   echo $this->Form->input('category_id'); // categories
   echo $this->Form->end('submit',true);
```

clear the cache, and this should work.

Comment: I get this Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /home/100141468/public_html/comp2084/todo/app/Controller/ProductsController.php on line 24 For the productsController

Comment: what is that line? Based on my code it could only be `$this->Product->Category->find()`; which suggests your models still aren't set up or the cache hasn't been cleared.